# Forbidden response headers

Tags: http, cookies, server, http-headers

I'm confused with forbidden response headers.
[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_response_header_name):

> A forbidden response header name is an HTTP header name (either `Set-Cookie` or `Set-Cookie2`) that cannot be modified programmatically.

But i surely **can** send cookie response manually.
So what does the word *programmatically* mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

That term comes from the [Fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) specification, which concerns sending requests and accessing responses from a program in the browser. *Programmatically* just means doing something from a program.

So, yes, your server can set the cookie to whatever it wants, but a Javascript program that receives that response will not be able to change the value of the header.